# Video doesn't scale correctly in width

Tags: html, css, video, screen, background-size

I have a slight issue. I have a video which I would like to adjust to the browser, it shouldn't stretch, but neither should there be any with space visible

#### HTML:

```
<video src="Wereldbol.mp4" onclick="this.play();" id='wereldbol' preload="auto" ></video>
```

#### CSS:

```
#wereldbol {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

`background-size: cover;` is causing the issue that the video would be off-center, is there any alternative way to cover the browser's full width and height? At the moment `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` don't quite fix the issue because it would leave the image to have a white bar on the left and right, eventhough the video scales correctly. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are trying to achieve is keep the video’s aspect ratio, but make it adapt to its surroundings without stretching the video out of proportion. Here’s how I do it:

Wrap the video element in a `div`, like this:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <video src="Wereldbol.mp4" onclick="this.play();" id='wereldbol' preload="auto" ></video>
</div>
```

Then use the following CSS:

```
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 56.25% 0 0 0; /* 100%/16*9 = 56.25% = Aspect ratio 16:9 */
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
}

.video-wrapper video {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

EDIT: Here’s a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AWGt8RH1acAPuntCLayc?p=preview): Adjust the viewport-width to see how it works.

Comment: Sir, this sortof works.. except that the video doesn't scale properly as a background-video.. the center is off and it has a slight border on the top and left of the video

Comment: Then I guess you’re searching for something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/AWGt8RH1acAPuntCLayc?p=preview

Comment: Sir, that is exactly what I am looking for, how would I go about programming such a design?

Comment: You can use the code in the plnkr, if you like. Just copy it, and replace the youtube iframe with your video.

Comment: By the way, since my answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: I was about to do so, is there no Jquery or Javascript required?

Comment: Sir, it works now, except for it scaling too far downwards, how can I solve this if I may ask?

Comment: I’m sorry, what do you mean with "scaling too far downwards"?

Comment: The video has the earth in the middle, the earth is missing a part on the bottom, it's not centered correctly

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: you need to adjust the aspect ratio, if your video is not formatted 16:9. For example, if it’s formatted 4:3, simply change `padding: 56.25% 0 0 0;` to `padding: 75% 0 0 0;` according to the formula in the comment of my CSS-code, above (100%/4*3 = 75%).

Answer (score 0):

You need to either adjust the CSS to fit the exact aspect-ratio using the ["aspect ratio trick"](http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/) or use something like FitVids.js -- see http://fitvidsjs.com/

Comment: FitVids probably works, but it either didn't solve your problem, or you didn't use it properly. Without knowing the exact solution you're after, I can't do anything more than point you to articles that **do** solve the problem of aspect ratio for videos. If you want a different solution, post a code example and/or a sketch of what you're after.